# Scope of a static variable to several files C++

Tags: c++, logging, static

I know that the scope and lifetime of a static variable is a widely documented topic on the internet.
However, I can't figure out how I should do it.

I have a namespace called `Logger` to log my program. This logger has a static variable `static bool verboseMode` that determines if the logs messages and files should be generated.

**logger.h**

```
namespace Logger
{
    static bool verboseMode;
    inline void printlog(const std::string_view message) {
        if(verboseMode) 
            std::cerr << message << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the logger from everywhere in my program, but `verboseMode` has the correct value only in the file where he was set.

For example if I have a `main.cpp` and a class `MyClass` like this :

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
    MyClass myclass;
    Logger::verboseMode = true;
    Logger::printlog("Log from main");
    myclass.test("Log from MyClass");
}
```

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {
public:
    void test(const std::string_view message){
        Logger::printlog(message);
    }
};
```

Here the `"Log from main"` message is generated, but not the `"Log from MyClass"` message.

I've heard that for a service like a logger you shouldn't create a class because a logger is not really an object. So you have to use a namespace.
But now how can I use my logger from anywhere, but configuring it only once at the beginning of my program?

Comment: This `static` means nothing. You have a copy of `verboseMode` in each translation unit (.cpp file) and this is against One Definition Rule.

Comment: Indeed each cpp file has its own `Logger::verboseMode` while I would like there to be only one. What would be a good solution?  
I just want to be able to use this service from anywhere without having to instantiate it in each file, and that this service can be configured.

Comment: I can't find any question referring to C++17 and `inline` variables, but the old solution will still work.